# Is there an easy way to convert a partial arc length or movement along an elliptic curve into an X,Y position?

Tags: conic-sections, elliptic-integrals, map-projections

I had this idea to project the Earth onto a 2D map using elliptical cylinders that could be unrolled.

(The Earth can be well approximated by rotating an ellipse on its axis to create an oblate spheroid. This in turn means only 60 horizontal elliptical secant cylinders would be enough to convert the planet to 2D map areas with a max error of less than 1 in 10000 as far as I can tell)

Long story short the lateral movements on the 2D map would correspond to a movement along an ellipse (when viewing the elliptical cylinder from the side).

So I would know the following:

- The elliptical parameters.
- The arc length moved (=2D_map_y).
- The origin from which the arc length movement began (y=0 both in the 2D map and for the ellipse/real space coordinates).

The elliptical integrals for finding arc lengths are beyond my math abilities and working backwards from there seems even more difficult.

I'm unashamedly looking for a potential answer/approximation without necessarily understanding it fully that I could put into a program.
Precision of 1:10000+ would be sufficient.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your description correctly, but, if I did, I'd like to ascertain one bit: Are all the ellipses you are working with going to be _quite_ close to circles? (as in, the difference between major and minor axis being smaller than 1%?

Comment: For the Earth or my use case that is correct.

Comment: For your information. An ellipse is not an [tag:elliptic-curve]. The origin of the name is way more complicated (the same with [tag:elliptic-equations]). Please read the tag descriptions before using them rather than selecting every tag containing the word *elliptic*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a fancier solution, but what I will do is to use the function "aelip(c, theta, a, b)".
(c being the distance moved on the curve and theta being the starting location/angle moved from)

I will make this function myself by constructing a fake ellipse using many circle or line segments. The amount of segments used will determine the level of precision.

I can do this because unlike the circumference of an ellipse it is easy to calculate precise points on the elliptic curve itself.
Three points on the elliptic curve should give me a circle with a locally closely fitting curve.

My program can then iterate through the segments to arrive at an angle from a specific movement on the curve.

Cheating you say? Well most of you likely don't think about what your calculator does when you press "PI", "cos" or such either.

I will update this answer with my code when it is done.

EDIT: It turns out that the existing mapping system UTM already maps to an elliptical cylinder from what I understand.

They use the so called Universal Transverse Mercator series by Krüger. I understand it as a series approximation of the ellipse instead of my proposed programmatic approach.

You can read about them here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transverse_Mercator_projection#Ellipsoidal_transverse_Mercator

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transverse_Mercator:_Redfearn_series

EDIT2:
I finished my programmatic solution, see here: https://github.com/Realpra1/EllipseMath

It's not optimized, but it seems to work and it's more precise than Ramanujan's best estimate formula as far as I can tell.

It's probably a lot slower than some series based estimate, but I said I would do it and post the code.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).